# MySql Query: Logical construction

Tags: mysql

I am quite new in MySql and I am struggling with a query.

I have 3 tables:

```
-users
    -user_id
    -username
    -password

-groups
    -group_id
    -group_name

-user_group_link
    -id
    -user_id (foreign key of users.user_id)
    -group_id (foreign key of groups.group_id)
```

Basically, I want the user_id of one user which has not joined the group with the id 5 (Every user can join multiple groups but can only join it once. Every group can have multiple users).
So something like this...

> SELECT users.user_id 
>  
>   FROM users, user_group_link 
>   WHERE users.user_id NOT IN (
>   UNION SELECT user_group_link.user_id, user_group_link.group_id 
>   WHERE user_group_link.group_id = 5)

Hopefully this can explain what I am trying to select. 
I would really appreciate if someone could help me construct this query.
Im stuck here for about 2 days and I really dont know what the Google for. I noticed that UNION SELECT or an INNER JOIN would fit for me.

Comment: remove the UNION word in your subquery ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the approach is to find all `user_id` available in `user_group_link` and then check which `user_id` from `users` table is not available in list of id from `user_group_link`.

The one option could be:

```
SELECT users.user_id 
FROM users
WHERE users.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_group_link.user_id FROM user_group_link 
WHERE user_group_link.group_id = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the user_id of one user which has not joined the group with the id 5

"I want the ids of all users that are not linked to group 5":

```
select user_id
  from users u
 where not exists (select 1
                     from user_group_link
                    where user_id = u.id
                      and group_id = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect opportunity to use EXCEPT.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM  users
EXCEPT
SELECT user_id
FROM  user_group_link
WHERE group_id = 5
```

This query will first select all user_ids from user_group_link table that ARE in group 5 and then it will select all user_ids from users table except these ids (the ids of the users in group 5).